# How to avoid IE redirecting to custom 404 page using javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect, anchor

I have below code.

```
<a href="">Text</a>
```

Other browsers just reloads the page when i click on 'Text' but IE11 redirects to my custom 404 page. Can somebody help me to reload the page if the anchor tag is empty and avoid redirecting to 404 page. Is there a way to do this in javascript.

Comment: Does it change the URL at all?

Comment: @Luca: In IE, it takes to my custom 404 url. But other browsers no.

Comment: `Is there a way to do this in javascript.`  ->  `window.location.reload()` ?

Comment: Do you want a link that refreshes the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `#` inside href, this might do it for you.

```
<a href="#">Text</a>
```

Dont Know why you want to do this, this needs to change according to your needs.

Comment: I initially thought that, but from what I can gather he wants to refresh the page,. Hash tags don't refresh..

Answer (score 0):

Just to keep the answers trivial as your code doesn't really explain the fuller context - would either of these work?

1. href="#"
2. href="http://www.absolute.link.to.your.page.html"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally location.reload() should do it as mentioned in the comments above (Keith)

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp